# Toggle button for sidebar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

I have a right sidebar.I'm using font awesome angle-left icon to show/hide the sidebar. On click of toggle button side bar pushes the content towards left along with the button & then button(font awesome left-angle) rotates 180 degrees to become (font awesome right-angle) as an animation. It is working fine till here. But when i scroll the page the toggle button is also getting scrolled vertically.

Here I don't want toggle button getting scrolled vertically every time.
I hv tried position: fixed in css by which vertical scrolling is stopped but the sidebar is not pushing the toggle button horizontally. The side bar is getting overlapped on the toggle button (only in firefox).

In chrome its working fine.The vertical scrolling is stopped & the sidebar is pushing the content to left side, but this is not happening in firefox.

**css:**

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  right: 0;
  -webkit-transition:  right 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition:  right 1s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition:  right 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition:  right 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: right 1s ease-in-out;
}

.container.open-sidebar {
  right: 240px;
}

#sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  right: -240px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  width: 240px;
  height: 100%;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 50px;
}

.content #sidebar-toggle {
  background: transparent;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0.5;
  border-radius: 1px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 30px 7px;
  float: right;
}

.padtop {
  line-height: 600px;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0.5;
  position: fixed;
}

.rotate {
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

.rotate.side {
  -moz-transform:rotate(180deg);
  -webkit-transform:rotate(180deg);
  transform:rotate(180deg);
}
```

**html:**

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-sm-1">
    <a href="#" data-toggle=".container" id="sidebar-toggle">
      <i class="fa fa-angle-double-left fa-5x padtop rotate"></i></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Here is my o/p:**
[o/p in Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cPTN.png)
[o/p in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9T3cv.jpg)

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in something like [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/57hdjprL/  Here is the JSFiddle @gaynorvader ..and can u pl find the image in the qtn ...i have got something like that...but i want that button to be pushed to left when sidebar is on screen..

Answer (score 0):

description and example demo for toggle effect..

[Demo](https://bufferwall.com/petersirka/2015-03-12-tutorial-simple-html-toggle-button/)

HTML

```
<div class="toggle-button">
    <button></button>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.toggle-button { background-color: white; margin: 5px 0; border-radius: 20px; border: 2px solid #D0D0D0; height: 24px; cursor: pointer; width: 50px; position: relative; display: inline-block; user-select: none; -webkit-user-select: none; -ms-user-select: none; -moz-user-select: none; }
.toggle-button button { cursor: pointer; outline: 0; display:block; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; border-radius: 100%; width: 30px; height: 30px; background-color: white; float: left; margin: -3px 0 0 -3px; border: 2px solid #D0D0D0; transition: left 0.3s; }
.toggle-button-selected { background-color: #83B152; border: 2px solid #7DA652; }
.toggle-button-selected button { left: 26px; top: 0; margin: 0; border: none; width: 24px; height: 24px; box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.1); }
```

Javascript

```
$(document).on('click', '.toggle-button', function() {
$(this).toggleClass('toggle-button-selected'); 
});
```

Comment: i have a button for the right sidebar(font awesome double-left angle) which is working fine.But the issue is when side bar is opened button should move along with it and when we close side bar it should go back to its initial position which is not happening in firefox. But its working fine in chrome. plz have a look at the o/p images in qtn  @sirajshaikh